# AngualrJs Dump Filter for View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, filter, dump

Who could share **filter** solution (*probably there is native solution for it*) that could **dump** data in AngularJs **view** templates(for **debugging** purposes)?

I'm looking something like:

```
<div>
{{somedata|dump}}
</div>
```

It could be not filter. The idea is to debug data that is coming to the view.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What is wrong with "dumping" the data using {{somedata}} ?

Comment: just want to see it styled. For big data objects it could be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found good one

```
app.directive("debug", function ($compile) {
    return {
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000000,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var clone = element.clone();
            element.attr("style", "color:red");
            clone.removeAttr("debug");
            var clonedElement = $compile(clone)(scope);
            element.after(clonedElement);
        }
    }
})
```

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-build-a-debug-directive

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking at some built-in solutions but I could not find anything at all.

I guess nobody would find such a thing really usefull since you have 2 decent solutions:

1. Outputing the data with `{{somedata}}`
2. Using Batarang. In case you are unfamiliar with Batarang please see the [github page](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/) or a short [introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-7mhcHXSfM)

I find investigating the scope data with Batarang is very efficient.

If you really think you could use the filter i guess you can code it yourself.
All you need to find is a treview control that displays json data and wrap that in an angular filter.

Regards